# Install .NET 4 via command line or PowerShell?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, command-line-interface, powershell, dotnet-framework

How do I install .NET 4 on Windows Server 2008 R2 from the command line or PowerShell?

[This post](http://sqlha.com/blog/2010/10/18/adding-net-framework-to-windows-server-2008-r2-part-one-command-line-and-powershell/) shows how to do it for .NET 3.5 using dism.exe and PowerShell. I am guessing that, since the .NET 4.0 binaries need to be downloaded first, these instructions do not work for .NET 4.

Comment: Do you mean 2008 R2?  Or do you actually mean RC2 as in a release candidate?

Comment: R2 - sorry about that

Comment: Your question might get more views if you edit it to fix the mistake.  You should also probably update your windows-server-2008 tag to windows-server-2008-r2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have done the following in Powershell:

```
((new-object net.webclient).DownloadFile("http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/5/A/95A9616B-7A37-4AF6-BC36-D6EA96C8DAAE/dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe","dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe")) 
& .\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe /q
```

There are other command line options than `/q` (for quiet). You can see those by doing:

`& .\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe /?`

[image: MessageBox resulting from running installer with the /? switch]

Comment: When I run /? I get nothing ...

Comment: Are you on a windows core system (with no GUI)? The help pops up in a window on my machine. Can you run the installer without the `/?` switch?

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that you don't have permissions to run the installer.

Comment: I may not have let it get that far? I expect those sorts of windows to come up right away, and instead it started rolling scrollbars, etc.

Comment: :) I agree that solution Microsoft came up with here is not really elegant. It is quite clunky to get a message box returned from a command line command.

Comment: Thanks for the updated picture, however, and it a) answered my question and b) should help others.

Comment: There's also `Invoke-WebRequest` for downloading files.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't specific to powershell, but might be of help.  After installing .NET3.5 we follow up using the full install binaries, simply running a silent install.  Depending on what and how you install this may require a reboot.

This how I've run silent installs of .NET4 in build/update scripts on 2003-2008R2 servers using the full install package:

- dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe /q

If you've not already stumbled across these, you might find them useful:

- [MSDN .NET Framework Deployment Guide for Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee942965%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)
- [Aaron Stebner's WebLog-Silent install, repair and uninstall command lines for the .NET Framework 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2010/05/12/10011664.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Just use command prompt.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -i
```

.net 4.0 installed automatically.